# JS class toggle not working with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple toggling of classes for multiple elements for a slide out menu without jQuery, pure JS.

```
function toggle_classes() {

        var navicon = document.getElementById('nav-icon');
        var overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');

        navicon.classList.toggle('open');
        overlay.classList.toggle('show');
    }

    document.querySelector('#nav-icon1').addEventListener('click', toggle_classes);
```

When I define the variables with `getElementById` it works, but it doesn't work with `getElementsByClassName`

**Can someone tell me how to fix this?** I'd much rather use `getElementsByClassName` so I can target multiple elements with a single line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data structure returned by `getElementsByClassName` is an array-like structure, not a dom element. so you must loop over the elements to toggle each one individually.

```
for (var i = 0; i < overlay.length; i++) {
  overlay[i].classList.toggle(...)
}
```

Comment: Technically it's an `HTMLCollection`

Comment: @PhilVarg Thank you, Do you have a go to resource for js documentation? I've tried searching for the returned value(s) of getElementsByClassName and can't find anything about array like structure. Obviously not looking for those exact words, but I thought it would be easily noted everywhere that mentions it. New to js, started with jQuery first. Thanks again

Comment: well the important thing to note here is that its not an individual dom element. its a collection of many dom elements. getElementById returns a single element, because there can (or should) only be one element per id. but many elements can have the same class, so `getElementsByClassName` returns many. as @SterlingArcher pointed out, (phrasing!), its not technically an array, but an HTMLCollection type. You were getting this error because the array (or specifically HTMLCollection) does not have a method classList, but a dom element does.

Comment: as far as documentation, i dont know of anything offhand, but you can open up a console and tinker around by doing `overlay.constructor` and you'll see its an `HTMLCollection` vs `navicon.constructor` and youll see its some `HTMLdomElement` such as `HTMLDivElement` (if its a div for instance)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName`... notice the "s" in Elements?

(in other words, that method returns an array, not a single element, so you need to do somehting like `overlay[0].etc`)

Comment: Thank you! This is an easy way to bypass the loop if one needed to use a unique class or very specific class over an ID. Will keep this up my sleeve.

Comment: another way to get a single element right away would be to use `document.querySelector(".overlay")` which returns the first element matching that selector.